# Cocoa/Objective-C - Verify if a key exist on a NSDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, nsdictionary

How do I verify if a key exists on a `NSDictionary`?

I know how to verify if it has some content, but I want to very if it is there, because it's dynamic and I have to prevent it. Like in some cases it could happen to have a key with the "name" and is value, but in another cases it could happen that this pair of value don't exists.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The simplest way is:

```
[dictionary objectForKey:@"key"] != nil
```

as dictionaries return `nil` for non-existant keys (and you cannot therefore store a nil in a dictionary, for that you use `NSNull`).

**Edit: Answer to comment on Bradley's answer**

You further ask:

> Is there a way to verify if this: [[[contactDetailsDictionary objectForKey:@"professional"] objectForKey:@"CurrentJob"] objectForKey:@"Role"] exists? Not a single key, because is a really giant dictionary, so it could exist in another category.

In Objective-C you can send a message to `nil`, it is not an error and returns `nil`, so expanding the simple method above you just write:

```
[[[contactDetailsDictionary objectForKey:@"professional"] 
                              objectForKey:@"CurrentJob"] 
                                objectForKey:@"Role"] != nil
```

as if any part of the key-sequence doesn't exist the LHS returns `nil`

Comment: For the chained lookup, you can also use KVC: `[contactDetailsDictionary valueForKeyPath:@"professional.CurrentJob.Role"]`.

Comment: There's a small typo in the 1st line of code, the method name is `objectForKey`, not `objectForkey`.

Answer (score 8):

`NSDictionary` returns all of the keys as an `NSArray` and then use `containsObject` on the array.

```
NSDictionary* dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"object", @"key"];
if ([[dictionary allKeys] containsObject:@"key"]) {
  NSLog(@"'key' exists.");
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to verify if this:

[[[contactDetailsDictionary objectForKey:@"professional"] objectForKey:@"CurrentJob"]objectForKey:@"Role"]]

exists? Not a single key, because is a really giant dictionary, so it could exist in another category.

Comment: Substitute `dictionary` with a call to a method returning an `NSDictionary`.

Comment: If the method returns the same thing, what's the need on doing that? Maybe that's a noob question, but I came from Front End and that Objective C is killing me slowly :P

Comment: I see what you mean.  Yeah, you could just assign the value to the dictionary variable and keep the `if` condition the same.

Comment: That reply is just awful. It's hard to imagine how you could do this in any more inefficient way. What a waste of memory and CPU time.